# style does not apply to ListView

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
    <head>

        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone-no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div data-role="page" id="main">


            <script type = "text/javascript" >
                $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#main', function() {


                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php",
                        jsonpCallback: 'yes',
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);

                            var markup = "";
                            $.each(data.list, function(i, elem) {
                                var $template = $('<li>    <div class=ui-grid-a >   <div class=ui-block-a   ><a  >' + "yes" + '</a> </div>  <div class=ui-block-b data-theme=a> ' + "vkmcmv" + '</div>  </div>   </li>');
                                $("#tweet-list").append($template);

                            });
                            $("#tweet-list").listview("refresh", true);


                        },
                        error: function(request, error) {
                            alert(error);

                        }
                    });


                });





            </script>


            <div data-role="header" class="logo">
                <img src="img/lanwa.png" />
                <br/>
                <h2>Lanwa Sales pad</h2>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">



                        <ul id="tweet-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" >

                        </ul>

            </div>

            <div data-role="footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

i tried above code to display items on a list view it works fine.But the design has not been
applied to the list view  though i import the default style sheet.Follwing image will show how the final out come loks like

[image: The List view image]

Comment: Kindly provide more Code, that would be helpful in answering your question. I don't think this is the reason, but it would be goo if you put quotes around your attributes:

var $template = $('<li>    <div class="ui-grid-a">   <div class="ui-block-a"> <a href="#">' + "yes" + '</a>  </div>  <div class="ui-block-b"> ' + "vkmcmv" + '</div>  </div>   </li>');

Also doublecheck your CSS if you have all the required classes around.

Comment: I add all default css files.i think that would be enough

Comment: Kindly describe how you want it to look like, from what I see it looks exactly like it should, according to what you have coded (quelle surprise).

Comment: Sorry for my english.Actuuly i need to display Listview with three columns with out affecting to the default theme.In my example link has underline .http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/4FdcY/ you can see in this example the style of links.in this example any external css was not applied except default css

Answer (score 0):

1.) If you need 3 Columns, you have to use `ui-grid-b` instead of `ui-grid-a`

2.) If I understand you correctly, you want to use a link that looks like a button (see [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html)). In that case, you'll have to put you the `data-role="button"` part in your link:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button">Link button</a>
```